# Two problems using Java / VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

The code below compiles on two online Java compilers, but I am having trouble with VS Code.

Two problems:

1. VS Code imports single items such as `import java.util.Arrays;` but does not import when using a wildcard like `import java.util.*;`
2. When executing(edit) the code below in VS Code, the following exception occurs:

   > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Entry cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable
   >       at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
   >       at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
   >       at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
   >       at EntryTester.main(EntryTester.java:33)

I don't know why the cast is a problem. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
    private String word;
    private String definition;
    public Entry(String wor, String def) {
        this.word = wor;
        this.definition = def;
    }
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    public String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return word + "\t" + definition;
    }
    public int compareTo(Entry other) {
        return word.compareTo(other.getWord());
    }
}

class EntryTester {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Entry[] wordList = new Entry[5];
        wordList[0] = new Entry("WWW", "World Wide Web");
        wordList[1] = new Entry("HTTP","Hypertext Transport Protocol");
        wordList[2] = new Entry("DNS", "Domain Name System");
        wordList[3] = new Entry("AWT", "Application Windowing Toolkit");
        wordList[4] = new Entry("CPU", "Central Processing Unit");
        Arrays.sort(wordList);
        for (int j = 0; j < wordList.length; j++)
            System.out.println(wordList[j].toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here...  There's 37 lines, the exception trace said line 38?

Comment: The exception you present ***does not*** occur when you compile.  It occurs when you execute the resulting program.

Comment: ... and it does not arise from the code presented, at least not for me.

Comment: I have edited. Yes, I meant executing. And yes, there is no problem with the code - hence why I say at the beginning - 'The code below compiles on two online Java compilers'. Please try to make helpful suggestions as to why I should have problems specifically with VS Code, as is indicated in the title of the question.

Comment: What line is line 38?

Comment: OK.. it's line 33. I edited some code as I was posting it. Apologies. Have edited.

Answer (score 1):

> VS Code imports single items such as `import java.util.Arrays;` but does not import when using a wildcard like `import java.util.*;`

Unclear what you mean by this.  But I suspect you are misunderstanding what a wildcard import means in Java:

- That import means to import classes in the `java.util` package.
- It does NOT include classes in subpackages such as `java.util.concurrent` and so on.

On the other hand, if you were expecting `import java.util.*;` to import the name of the `Arrays::sort` static methods, it doesn't.  And neither does `import java.util.Arrays;`!   If you want to import status methods you need to do this:

```
  import static java.util.Arrays.*;
```

If the Visual Studio Java *compiler* is telling you something different, something is very wrong.

(Comment: Most programmers tend to avoid wildcard imports in production code.  You can get into problems if names declared in multiple packages.)

---

> When executing(edit) the code below in VS Code, the following exception occurs:
>
> ```
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
>           Entry cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable
> ```

When you sort a list using the `Arrays.sort`, there are two ways that the `sort` method can order the elements of your `Entry[]`

- You can supply a `Comparator<Entry>` argument to the `sort` method.
- The `Entry` class can `implement` the `Comparable<Entry>` interface.

If you *don't* provide a `Comparator`, the `sort` method *assumes* that you are doing it the other way.  So it is now trying cast one of the `Entry` objects to `Comparable` so that it can call `entry.compareTo(anotherEntry)` on it.   Which fails ...

In your case, it appears that you have implemented `Comparator` in `Entry`.

So there are two possible explanations:

1. You may be executing an old version of your code; i.e. one from *before* you modified `Entry` to implement `Comparable`.
2. There may be something broken with your Visual Studio.

---

If we can assume the the problem is with Visual Studio Code, I suspect it is related to Java versions.  The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) states that Java 11 is supported, but it may also be necessary to *tell* VS that it is using Java 11 rather than Java 8.  (There are some significant runtime differences due to the introduction of modules in Java 9 ....)

Comment: Could you say why it fails? Also, why would it execute elsewhere, but not in VS Code?

Comment: Short answer: your VS Code is possibly broken or misinstalled / misconfigured.   I would use NetBeans, Intellij or Eclipse in preference.  Or even the JDK tool chain.